# Custom Buttons - Error in Java - widget.Button;

Tags: android-widget

Followed example to the letter. When I try to use a custom button via a custom.xml, emulator crashes with a Java error - inflating class android.widget.Button.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MasterActivity extends Activity {

    Button uccBtn, tipBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_master);

        uccBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tipBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        uccBtn.setOnClickListener (uccApp);
        tipBtn.setOnClickListener (tipApp);

custom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_ecolab_selected"></item>
<item android:state_focused="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/btn_ecolab_highlight"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_ecolab"></item>
</Selector>

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background ="#ffffcc"
tools:context=".MasterActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/button1" android:typeface="serif"
    android:background="@drawable/custom"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/version"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="@string/button10" android:typeface="serif"
    android:background="@drawable/custom" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:text="@string/button2" android:typeface="serif"
    android:background="@drawable/custom"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I reference just the button by name (btn_ecolab), it works fine, just no animation of the buttons when pressed or selected. I've tried it with a LinearLayout to make sure that the Relitavelayout was not the problem. The custom buttons are in my Res/drawable-hpdi folder. Also tried copies of buttons and custom.xml in the -mdpi, -xhdpi and -xxhdpi. Tried without @string assignments.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
uccBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
tipBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
uccBtn.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {              
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //your code is here
                }
            });
```

make one folder drawable in res folder put your **custom.xml**

I am using this way and work great.

Comment: I have the custom.xml in the res/drawable folder already. I have the "new(onclickListener)' later in the code. Again, everything works unless I use "custom" in the activity_main.xml. If I use btncustom(.png) it works fine. It errors on import android.widget.Button.